# Should you have an class interface function that calls other internal functions?

Tags: c++

I am looking for the best practices for designing a class interface.

Say you have a class function that loads an image, does exception checking and if it passes adds it to a map class.

Is it best to have 1 function:

```
public void SomeClass::Load( Type::Something ID //enum, std::string& fileName )
{
    // Load file from string
    // Do Exception checking
    // Add to map
    // Assert std::map.insert
}
```

2 functions:

```
public void SomeClass::Load( Type::Something ID //enum, std::string& fileName )
{
    // Load file from string
    // Do Exception checking
    // Call insert
}   
private void SomeClass::Insert( Type::Something ID //enum, std::string& fileName )
{
    // Map.insert
    // assert check
}
```

One Public function that calls a private function

Or 3 functions:

```
public void SomeClass::Load( Type::Something ID //enum, std::string& fileName )
{
    // Call Load
    // Call insert
}   
private void SomeClass::LoadFromFile( Type::Something ID //enum, std::string& fileName )
{
    // Load file from string
    // Do Exception checking
    // Call insert
}   
private void SomeClass::Insert( Type::Something ID //enum, std::string& fileName )
{
    // Map.insert
    // assert check
}
```

One function that's public that just calls 2 private functions.

Comment: I think your question is opinion based. For example I wouldn't use exceptions in this simple task. As Herbert said exceptions are for something exceptional (e.g., a bullet hit your CPU).

Comment: The real question is what is the goal of the software, also is their a reason for such encapsulation ie security or data structure protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good idea to divide your functions up so that they each perform a single task. Sometimes that means introducing some private member function as you have shown. However, as with any function, you should make sure you only make it a member function if necessary - that is, when it requires access to the class's private data members. Often, you may be able to write these functions as non-members that are declared only in the class's `.cpp` file (so they are not exported for other translation units).

However, I'm not sure if the way you've structured this is appropriate. Of course, I don't know what `SomeClass` represents, but does loading the image actually depend on the state of `MyClass`. If not, perhaps `Load` should be a non-member function for loading images and you should pass the result to a public `Insert` function:

```
Image image = Load(/* whatever */);
myClass.Insert(image);
```

As an aside, I do wonder if you should be handling exceptions in this function. I think a good way to think about exceptions is: throw an exception if your function is unable to fulfil its contract with the calling code. In this case, `SomeClass::Load`'s contract promises to load an image. If it can't do that, it should let the exception propagate (or wrap it in another one). Only handle an exception when handling it actually helps to fulfil the contract.

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning. The code is from a book, it starts with 1 and then moves to 2.  I am reading multiple books at once and it seems like 3 might be best what the code is actually doing I guess isn't really the question it's more of if you have a general function like load or do something thats 17 steps should you create a function for each of the 17 steps in private functions if noone needs outside access and then create an 18th function thats public someone can call to do everything else.

Comment: @MK Every single function in your code should do a logically distinct task. That is, you should be able to sum up what it does in a single sentence with no "and"s. If you look at the body of a function and it looks like it's doing *this* and then *that*, you should probably split it up. If not, don't. There's a bit of an art to this.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. There is no "right" answer here. It's largely down to personal preference, and of course "how much code is it".

There is also a principle that "a function should do one thing, and do that well". But what "one thing" is really depends on how you look at things. If a function is "loading" a file by reading it's content and inserting the components from the file into a map, that may well be your `Load` function. But if you have other parts of your code that also insert into the map, splitting the function to have a separate `Insert` function is probably a great idea.

In general, repeated code is bad, so if you find yourself having "the same" (or very similar) code in several places, then it's time to consider making that bit of code into a function.

Private member functions are a good solution for this in general, if you find that you "need to".

I typically prefer small functions whenever possible.